# How to get formula between parenthesis with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Normally, a formula with parenthesis, followed by a digit, has to be multiplied. For example:

```
(2* 4)(2*1-1)3 is equals to (2 *4)\*(2*1-1)*3
```

But i want to split a string after the parenthesis, i think with an regex. After that, i want to calculate it with mathjs as individual formulas.

What i want:

```
(2* 4)(2*1-1)3 = 813
```

A complete string, including multiple parenthesis:

```
N 52 11. (1+(3+2 ) /2) (56* 7)( 2*1-1) 7 E 005 36. (1+7) 9 (6*1)
```

The regex i have now: `/\([0-9+\-\(* \/]+\)/g`

But that doesnt match the digits and gives a problem with double parenthesis.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: i didnt know that it make sense, but it is javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to validate the content of the parenthesis at this point, simply use a regex based on parenthesis and nothing else :

```
\([^)]*\)
```

This will match an open parenthesis, followed by optional other characters, followed by a closed parenthesis.

If you don't want to match empty parenthesis, change the `*` into `+`.